# Adding hosts to existing 2012r2 Hyper-V cluster

Tags: hyper-v, cluster, windows-server-2012-r2, host

Situation:

Two separate clusters, server 2012 and server 2012r2

In process of disassembling the 2012 cluster and upgrading those hosts to 2012r2

Prior to this I must move all of the guests to the 2012r2 cluster, but there isn't enough space

I'm adding a temporary host for the VMs that are currently on 2012, but last I knew when adding a host you need to validate the cluster, which puts all of the VMs in a saved state and creates massive down time

Does anybody have input on how to add a host to a cluster without bringing the cluster down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What takes the VM's offline during a validation is testing the storage system. You can skip that part of the validation.

Also, you aren't *required* to validate a cluster when a host is joined. If you want Microsoft to support you, they will ask you for a validation report. But you don't need long term support from them for your temporary solution.